# C# SQL Connection not found

Tags: c#, mysql

How can I connect a SQL database in C#?

My code:

```cs
const string connectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;User ID=root;Database=MyDatabase;Password=MyPassword";
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
```

I get: Error: 40 - could not open a connection to sql server. I tried also in Python and it worked well:

```py
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='MyPassword', host='127.0.0.1', database='MyDatabase')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
```

What am I missing in C#?

Comment: I think "Database" is called Initial Catalog, but besides that it looks correct

Comment: `SqlConnection` is for Microsoft SQL Server, but it looks like you've actually got MySQL. You should look into the MySQL drivers available for .NET, e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: you can validate your connection string on this page https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use MySqlConnection for MySql DB.

```
            const string connectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;User ID=root;Database=MyDatabase;Password=MyPassword";         
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString );
            conn.Open();

            string sqlcommand = "SELECT Query";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlcommand , conn);
```

Comment: Yes, with MySQL it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please follow this example

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

var connectionString = "server=serveradress;database=dbName;user id=sqluser;password=abc;";

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    
    using var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName ", connection);
    var Count = command.ExecuteScalar();

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {Count } movies");
}
```

server adress in general is `127.0.0.1` ,if you are working locally

here the source page :
[example](https://makolyte.com/csharp-connect-to-a-mysql-database/)
and also consider reading this page here [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-standard.html)